# Getting value of an Input in an list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of an input field in a html list.
I don't want the value which I set as the page loaded, i want the changed value (typed something in like abcd).

I tried it with innerHTML, innerText, textContent but its all the theme the old value.
The only thing that works ist getting the value with the id from input, but that does not work for me and my project.

May anyone can help me.

Here is the list code:

```
<li id="testlist">
    <img onclick="functionxyz()" src="" height="40px" ondblclick="" width="50px"></img>
    <input id="id1" class="textlist" type="text" name="" value="old value"></input>
    <select id="id2" class="selectshortlist" name=""></select>
    <textarea id="" class="textfield1" cols="1" maxlength="1000" rows="1" name=""></textarea>
    <div class="ui-state-default sortable-number"></div>
    <input type="button" class="removelist"></input>
</li>
```

And that's the JavaScript code:

```
function()
{
    var sort1 = document.getElementById("testlist");
    alert(sort1);
    var liste = sort1;
    alert(liste.value);
    alert(liste.innerHTML);
    var savelist = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < liste.length; i++)
    {
        alert(liste[i].value);
        console.log(liste[i].value)
        //savelist.push(liste[i].textContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('yourinput').val()`?

Comment: Don't put a closing tag after inputs - they should be self-closing... `<input id="blah" value="blah" etc="blah" />`

Comment: Do you want the change in the value as the value in the text box changes?

Comment: When is your function invoked? Is it ever invoked?

Comment: no, i am usung xml and a process engine to simulate a serverside. i ned the changes clientside in a variable and the rest does the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this with jquery, so the answer is, use jquery :)

```
var valueThatYouSeek = $('#testlist input.textlist').val();
console.log(valueThatYouSeek);
alert(valueThatYouSeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without jquery pretty easily if you're going that route.

```
function getInputVal() {
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("textlist")[0];
    console.log(input.value);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a9LZs/)